# ZSH Bindkey Reverse Lookup

Tags: linux, zsh, ansi-escape, terminfo

Can anyone tell me what the key sequence is for these?
I know if I do `cat` and type key presses I can get the code for it but how do I reverse that process to figure out what to press for beginning-of-line, for example?

```
bindkey '^[^[[D' backward-word
bindkey '^[^[[C' forward-word

bindkey '^[[5~' up-line-or-history
bindkey '^[[A' up-line-or-search
bindkey '^[[B' down-line-or-search
bindkey '^[[6~' down-line-or-history

bindkey '^[[5D' beginning-of-line
bindkey '^[[5C' end-of-line

bindkey '^[[3~' delete-char
bindkey '^?' backward-delete-char 

bindkey '^[^N' newtab
bindkey '^[[Z' reverse-menu-complete
```

Comment: Do you think you could accept my answer?

Answer (score 1):

> Tip: I've now published a more sophisticated version of the
> code below as part of the [`zsh-edit`
> plugin](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-edit).

---

You can use this function to do a reverse bindkey lookup:

```sh
reverse-bindkey-lookup() {
  print ${(k)terminfo[(Re)$(print -b - $1)]}
}
```

For example, when I run:

```sh
% reverse-bindkey-lookup '^[[Z'
```

I get as output:

```sh
cbt kcbt
```

These values you can then look up by doing

```sh
% man terminfo
```

and pressing <kbd>/</kbd> to search.

For the example above, I find:

```
back_tab                    cbt      bt     back tab (P)
```

and

```
key_btab                    kcbt     kB     back-tab key
```

Another example: If I run

```sh
% reverse-bindkey-lookup '^[[3~'
```

I get

```sh
kdch1
```

which `man terminfo` says is

```
key_dc                      kdch1    kD     delete-character key
```

Hopefully, you can then figure out from there what the actual key on your keyboard would be.

Comment: @maletor Does this answer your question?

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea how to do reverse look up in general, just to provide some information for my Terminal (which should mimic `xterm`). This is done by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd> (`quoted-insert`); replacing `^[` with `\e` for clarity.

- `\e[5~` / `\e[6~` are <kbd>PgUp</kbd> <kbd>PgDn</kbd>
- `\e[A` to `\e[D` are arrow keys <kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd>
- `^?` is <kbd>← Backspace</kbd>
- `\e[3~` is <kbd>Delete</kbd>